# Javascript nested square brackets in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for an easier (and less hacky) way to get the substring of what is inside matching square brackets in a string. For example, lets say this is the string:

```
[ABC[D][E[FG]]HIJK[LMN]]OPQR[STUVW]XYZ
```

I want the substring:

```
ABC[D][E[FG]]HIJK[LMN]
```

Right now, I am looping through the string and counting the open and closed brackets, and when those numbers are the same, I take substring of the first open bracket and last closed bracket.

Is there an easier way to do this (ie with regex), so that I do need to loop through every character?

Comment: Do you also want to match/capture `[STUVW]`?

Comment: @Mathletics No, that is not needed.

Comment: You're parsing a little language, with nesting. There is nothing hacky whatsoever about iterating over the characters in the input--that's what parsers do. What would be hacky is a hard-to-read, hard-to-maintain, limited regexp such as was suggested in one answer.

Comment: @torazaburo Hey, thanks, I think your right; I am just going to leave it as is. I just thought that if there was an easier and clean way with regex, I could use that instead.

Comment: Is this an array? What is this supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach, an ugly hack which turns the input into a JS array representation and then parses it using `JSON.parse`:

```
function parse(str) {
    return JSON.parse('[' +
        str.split('') . join(',') .  // insert commas
            replace(/\[,/g, '[')  .  // clean up leading commas
            replace(/,]/g, ']')   .  // clean up trailing commas
            replace(/\w/g, '"$&"')   // quote strings
        + ']');
}

>> hack('A[B]C')
<< ["A", ["B"], "C"]
```

Now a stringifier to turn arrays back into the bracketed form:

```
function stringify(array) {
    return Array.isArray(array) ? '[' + array.map(stringify).join('') + ']' : array;
}
```

Now your problem can be solved by:

```
stringify(parse("[ABC[D][E[FG]]HIJK[LMN]]OPQR[STUVW]XYZ")[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get the question right (sorry about that).

So you mean that if you were to have a string of characters **X**, you would like to check if the string combination **Y** is contained within **X**?

Where **Y** being `ABC[D][E[FG]]HIJK[LMN]`

If so then you could simply do:

`var str = "[ABC[D][E[FG]]HIJK[LMN]]OPQR[STUVW]XYZ";`

`var res = str.match(/ABC\[D]\[E\[FG]]HIJK\[LMN]/);`

The above would then return the string literal **Y** as it matches what is inside str.

It is important that you pay attention to the fact that the symbols [ are being escaped with a \. This is because in regex if you were to have the two square brackets with any letter in between (ie. [asd]) regex would then match the single characters included in the specified set.

You can test the regex here:
https://regex101.com/r/zK3vZ3/1

Comment: Aha, so literally, why not just `res = 'ABC[D][E[FG]]HIJK[LMN]'`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is to get all characters from an opening square bracket up to the *corresponding* closing square bracket. *Balancing groups* are not implemented in JavaScript, but there is a workaround: we can use several optional groups between these square brackets.

The following regex will match up to 3 nested `[...]` groups and you can add the capturing groups to support more:

`\[[^\]\[]*(?:
 \[[^\]\[]*(?:
    \[[^\]\[]*(?:\[[^\]\[]*\])*\]
  )*[^\]\[]*
 \][^\]\[]*
 )*[^\]\[]*
\]`

See [example here](https://regex101.com/r/cC8gQ4/1). However, performance may be not that high with such heavy backtracking.

**UPDATE**

Use [`XRegExp`](http://xregexp.com/):

```js
var str = '[ABC[D][E[FG]]HIJK[LMN]]OPQR[STUVW]XYZ';

// First match:
var res = XRegExp.matchRecursive(str, '\\[', ']');
document.body.innerHTML = "Getting the first match:<br/><pre>" + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4) + "</pre><br/>And now, multiple matches (add \"g\" modifier when defining the XRegExp)";

// Multiple matches:
res = XRegExp.matchRecursive(str, '\\[', ']', 'g');
document.body.innerHTML += "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/2.0.0/xregexp-all-min.js"></script>
```